# Update value in one table if something happens in another

Tags: mysql

How could I update a value in my table when something occurs in another?

For example,

I have a `like` table set up, and when someone likes a Post, I would like the 'numberOfLikes' in the 'Posts' table to increase.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides just doing an `update` at the same time as `insert`ing the like, you could create a trigger on the `like` table to update the `posts` table.

```
delimiter |

create trigger likepost after insert on like
  for each row begin
    update posts set likes = likes + 1 where post_id = new.post_id;
  end;
|

delimiter ;
```

(The above was quickly adapted from [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html), so you'll have to change it for your actual schema design.)

You would also need to create trigger(s) that handle the removal of likes, as well.

Comment: I edited it to fit the purpose, and I got the error: Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation. I know it doesn't cause the error, but my code is: `delimiter | CREATE trigger likepost AFTER INSERT ON Likes
FOR each
ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE Posts SET numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes +1 WHERE id = postID;

END ;

| delimiter;`

Comment: That would need to be `WHERE id = NEW.postID` because `NEW` represents the new row in `Likes` that you just inserted, so you need to reference that field. However, the "Access denied" message means the MySQL user does not have privileges to create triggers.

Comment: How could I allow me(the user) to have that privilege?

Comment: If you don't have access to a super user in the database, or know someone else who has the permissions to add the triggers to that database, you're probably just not going to be able to do it this way. If that's the case, there's nothing wrong with doing an `insert` and then an `update` without using triggers, like tbleckert's answer. I don't like putting much code in triggers, but this seems acceptably simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're adding in the likes table, but this is what you should do in the post table.

```
UPDATE Posts set numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes + 1 WHERE post_id = 'x'
```

That's the query, just run that when someone likes a post.

For example:

```
<a href="?like=5">Like this post</a>
```

And then

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['like']) && is_numeric($_GET['like'])) {
        $update = mysql_query("UPDATE Posts set numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes + 1 WHERE post_id = '".$_GET['like']."'");

        if ($update) {
            echo "Thank you sir!";
        } else {
            echo "Oups, try again!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Oh, seems like I missunderstood the question...sorry :)